# Unable to use column into sub query - MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm unable to use this 'enquiries.enquiry_id' column into sub query. I've also tried with alias of table but didn't got success into this 
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'enquiries.enquiry_id' in 'where clause'

Can we use another way for this?

```
Tables
------------------------------
Enquiries
------------------------------
enquiry_id | name 
1            A
2            B
3            C
4            D
------------------------------
Bookings
------------------------------
booking_id | name |enquiry_id 
1            A      1
2            B      2
3            C      2   
4            D      3
------------------------------


SELECT 
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                booking_id
            FROM
                bookings
            WHERE
                enquiry_id = enquiries.enquiry_id) AS t) AS total
FROM
    enquiries
WHERE
    enquiry_id = 2
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is your use too many subquery. The first subquery can know enquire, but the second depth doesnt

Comment: it's not actual  query it's just sample but i want same logic in my actual query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your query can be simplify like

```
SELECT COUNT(e.booking_id) as total
FROM  enquiries e
WHERE e.enquiry_id = 2
```

Or In case you need something else from `booking`

```
SELECT COUNT(b.booking_id)  as total
FROM  bookings b
JOIN  enquiries e
  ON b.enquiry_id = e.enquiry_id 
WHERE e.enquiry_id = 2
```

And to show you how fix your query.

```
SELECT 
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM  bookings b
         WHERE b.enquiry_id = e.enquiry_id) AS total            
FROM
    enquiries e
WHERE
    enquiry_id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, I did same above logic in my actual query but calculation comes wrong as per my requirement. I want multiples tables column calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I did same above logic in my actual query but calculation comes wrong as per my requirement. I want multiples tables column calculation.

Comment: provide a complete example in rextester.com with expected output and maybe we can help you better